# Making an observable 'run' synchronously

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-extensions-js

I have a situation in which I need to wait for the observable to begin emitting values before the subsequent code executes. The closest I have gotten so far is like this:

```
async ensureContentLoaded() {
  if (!this.content) {
    defer(async () => {
      this.content = await this.getContent();
      console.log(`Got content`);
    }).subscribe();

    console.log(`Finished`);
  }
```

At the moment, the `Finished` console log is appearing before the `Got content`. I want the observable to 'block' until it starts to emit values. Note that `this.getContent()` returns a promise; although it could easily return an observable if that makes any difference. Also I know that `this.content` is referring to the wrong context, but that's another issue.

How can I create an observable that will block execution until a value is emitted?

Comment: what you ask is impossible in the general case - JavaScript engines are single-threaded, which means if you block the single thread to wait for an observable to produce a value, then there is no thread available for that async mechanism to run and produce its value

Comment: describe _why_ you need this.  The solution to your problem is _not_ to block while waiting on the observable.  It is to make your other code asynchronous.

Comment: Why not structure the code such that upon receiving the first value the code executes, rather than trying to block until then. To put it another way, execute a given callback when the first value emitted by a observable.

Comment: I don't understand. If `getContent()` returns an `Observable`, why not  `getContent().subscribe(() => console.log('Got content'))` ?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. You're absolutely right Brandon and francium. I need to make the consuming code run asynchronously. I'll do it like that.

Comment: I am not sure if this scenario and refactoring I did will be of some help to you - but this may give you some ideas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150472/is-angulars-foreach-loop-over-an-object-asynchronous/54808339#54808339

Answer (score 0):

THe following code should be sufficient.

```
ensureContentLoaded() {
  if (this.content) return of(this.content);
  return from(this.getContent());
}
// usage 
this.ensureContentLoaded().subscribe(console.log);
// or turn it to promise if needed
this.ensureContentLoaded().pipe(toPromise()).then(...)
```